# После отправки формы переходит на страницу /includes/sendmail.php, как остаться на той же странице?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Создал форму отправки письма через sendmail.php, форма работает, письмо приходит.
Но после отправки переходит на страницу /includes/sendmail.php с сообщением об удачной отправке сообщения, ка мне остаться на той же странице?
Пробую js с event.preventDefault(); но всё равно происходит перенаправление
js взял из доков к теме, не сильно понимаю как работает, прошу камнями не кидаться))

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var form_btn = $(form).find('button[type="submit"]');
        var form_result_div = '#form-result';
        $(form_result_div).remove();
        form_btn.before('<div id="form-result" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: block;">hello</div>');
        var form_btn_old_msg = form_btn.html();
        form_btn.html(form_btn.prop('disabled', true).data("loading-text"));
        form.preventDefault();
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            dataType:  'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if( data.status == 'true' ) {
                    $(form).find('.form-control').val('');
                }
                form_btn.prop('disabled', false).html(form_btn_old_msg);
                $(form_result_div).html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                setTimeout(function(){ $(form_result_div).fadeOut('slow') }, 6000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: У вас в форме в поле action  указан `includes/sendmail.php` ?